# Does sharpness decrease with higher F-stop numbers?

Tags: macro

Im quoting a paragraph that I read from where my questions arises:................... 
"Macro photography often has an extremely shallow depth of field, so sacrificing some resolution is usually acceptable. With digital SLR cameras, aperture settings of f/11-f/16 provide a good trade-off between depth of field and resolution, but f/22+ is often necessary for extra (but softer) depth of field."

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [What is a "diffraction limit"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/what-is-a-diffraction-limit) explains why although I can see why you would not be able to find that if you did not know the term "diffraction limit" already.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11205/do-smaller-apertures-provide-more-depth-of-field-past-the-diffraction-limit-eve is a good source of information, too.

Comment: Since this answer isn't actually providing any new information, I marked it as Community Wiki. Please edit any added links to other questions right into the answer.