# What is the effect of changing the Aperture

Tags: aperture, aperture-priority

What is the effect of changing the Aperture on the quality of the image?

Comment: Check also [Do smaller apertures provide more depth of field past the diffraction limit, even if peak sharpness suffers?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11205/17441) for some nice sample photos in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Making the aperture smaller (F/2.8 is smaller than F/1.4) will cause increased depth of field, a darker exposure, and in some cases will result in increased sharpness. However, making the aperture too small can result in diffraction which makes the image softer. Also, small apertures result in starbursts from light sources if that's what you're after.