# What is the Nikon D3200's diffraction limit?

Tags: macro, nikon-d3200, diffraction

I'm new to the world of macro so do bear with me! I shoot pictures of fish through aquariums, so normally this means the lens is always perpendicular to the glass surface to avoid blurring.

However the cost of a perpendicularly positioned lens is that, if the fish is not presenting itself along its lateral aspect, I can't tilt. This leads to some  unflattering head-only shots.

So I'm trying to find the highest aperture for my camera body, but want to avoid diffraction limiting the photo and adding more blur than I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more complex than the question seems to indicate. Intended display size also comes into play. This is because the *Diffraction Limited Aperture (DLA)* of a sensor is only the *beginning* of the effects of diffraction and the image must be viewed at full size (1 image pixel=1 monitor pixel) for the effect of that diffraction to be seen. Unless you are viewing your images at sizes approaching 60x40 inches with a 22MP camera you won't be able to see the effects of diffraction until well past the *DLA*.

For more about what the *DLA* is and what considerations should be weighed when deciding to use a particular aperture, please see [Does sensor size impact the diffraction limit of a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76119/does-sensor-size-impact-the-diffraction-limit-of-a-lens/76125#76125) and [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/34034/15871) to [Do smaller apertures provide more depth of field past the diffraction limit, even if peak sharpness suffers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11205/do-smaller-apertures-provide-more-depth-of-field-past-the-diffraction-limit-eve/34034#34034)

Just for reference, the Nikon D3200 has a pixel pitch of 3.8µm. That gives a *DLA* of between f/6.0 and f/6.1. But keep in mind diffraction will only be evident at f/6 if you are displaying the images at 100% magnification on your monitor or printing at 60x40"!