# Which one captures sharper photo Nikon 50mm f/1.8G vs 35mm f/1.8G on D5200?

Tags: 35mm, 50mm, nikon-d5200

I want to do portrait photography that's why I am considering to buy a prime lens. I want sharp photographs with intense blur. I am aware of the fact that 50mm will act like 75mm after sensor crop.

- I have also heard that FX lens on DX format camera gives extra sharp
  photos. is it correct?
- also please tell me which one will give more bokeh effect?
- I will be doing outdoor photoshooting so 75mm shouldn't be much
  problem for me right?

Comment: Hello Robin, welcome to SE.Photography. Your question seems to be a possible duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25350/50mm-vs-85mm-for-portraits-on-a-crop-sensor, at least partially

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nikkor f/1.8G 35mm or 50mm?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/nikkor-f-1-8g-35mm-or-50mm)

Comment: "Portraits" is a little broad. It can describe anything from tight head shots to environmental portraits.

Answer (score 1):

The D5200 has a crop factor of 1.5, so as you wrote, the 50mm will become 75mm and the 35mm a little over 52mm. Most photographers consider that portraits are best taken with a equivalent focal length of 70mm or greater (See [Nikkor f/1.8G 35mm or 50mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/nikkor-f-1-8g-35mm-or-50mm) and [50mm vs 85mm for portraits on a crop sensor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25350/50mm-vs-85mm-for-portraits-on-a-crop-sensor)).

You can make also some statistics on the portraits you probably already have taken with the zoom from you lens kit and compare the focal length. I'm betting that most of those have a focal length above a 60mm equivalent (40mm on your DSLR).

If you are committed to buy a Nikon lens for portrait, I would go for the 50mm. The reviews of this lens appear to agree :

- https://photographylife.com/nikon-35mm-f1-8g-vs-50mm-f1-4g
- http://www.btobey.com/nikon/nikon-35mm-18-vs-50mm-18.php